# Get Locale Date Format Information

Tags: swift, locale, date-formatting

Using Swift 4, is there a way to get a string representation of a locale's date format?  Based on an iPhone's locale settings, I would like to find out if the format is yyyy/mm/dd or mm/dd/yyyy.

I've found all of the ways for changing a date format or getting the date from the locale's format but have not been able to work out how to get the actual format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `DateFormatter dateFormat(fromTemplate:options:locale:)`.

```
let userFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "yyyyMMdd", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)
```

In the US this returns `MM/dd/yyyy`. In Germany this gives `dd.MM.yyyy`.

If you ever need to get the appropriate time format which also takes into account the user's chosen 12/24-hour time format, use a template of `jms`. The `j` is a special format specifier, only used with templates, that returns either `h` or `H` for the hour depending on what's appropriate.

---

Another possible option is to create a `DateFormatter`, set the desired `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`, then read the `dateFormat` property:

```
var mydf = DateFormatter()
mydf.dateStyle = .long // set as desired
mydf.timeStyle = .full // set as desired
print(mydf.dateFormat)
```

For the US this gives:

> MMMM d, y 'at' h:mm:ss a zzzz

For Germany this gives:

> d. MMMM y 'um' HH:mm:ss zzzz